# Different PHP versions on CLI, phpinfo and Laravel exception

Tags: php, laravel, server

I'm currently running a shared server with the multi PHP manager cPanel extension, so I'm trying to install Laravel 5.7, but I get the following exception:

> Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.7.* in a version
>   installable using your PHP version 5.6.38.

But when I run `php -v`, it outputs the following:

```
PHP 7.2.11 (cli) (built: Oct 30 2018 20:57:09) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.2.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by ionCube Ltd.
```

And if I do a `phpinfo()`, I get the following version:

```
PHP Version 7.0.32
```

So, as you can see all 3 versions are different and I don't know what is going on, any ideas?

**NOTE: I don't have super user permissions, when I run commands with sudo I get the following :** `sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?`

Comment: find in phpinfo() output page the loaded .ini config file and go from there

Comment: The php.ini path is the following: `/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.ini`, but why does the exception thrown says I'm at 5.6.38?

Comment: How did you run composer? Have you tried setting a target PHP version like documented at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847258/use-php-7-to-run-composer-but-install-packages-for-php-5

Comment: @NicoHaase For installing the project I ran the folllowing command: `composer create-project laravel/laravel="5.7.*" myProject` because I wanted to force 5.7 installation (if I ran the command with prefer dist it would install 5.4). Now, if I add the platform on the composer file I get the following error when running `composer update`:
`syntax error, unexpected '?' in myProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 233`

Comment: Have you tried changing the PHP version from your cPanel, if you can? The PHP version your CLI uses is ultimately determined by which version it finds first in your $PATH variable, but your webserver doesn't run it this way and needs to be set explicitly. Laravel 5.7 requires PHP >= 7.1.3

Comment: @TravisBritz Yeah, I think I will be stucked with this specific server, since I would need to restart apache in order to make the web server use PHP 7.2.11 and I don't have the right permissions to do it. I think I will need to install the project on a lower Laravel version and dependencies in my local machine and then upload it,