# It is possibile to use composer with php71 simulating an environment with php70?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've installed version 7.1 of php. I am developing a library that may work on different php version. I want to run ...

```
composer install
```

simulating an environment with php70. The purpose is to avoid php packages in composer.lock that require php71. Is it possibile?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add something like:

```
"config": {                                                                       
    "platform": {                                                                
        "php": "~7.0.0"
    }
}
```

into your `composer.json`. This should fix the platform for dependency libs.

More info to be found here: [Force composer to require PHP Version between Version X and Version Y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26277151/2915423)

Comment: I had to change it to: "php": "7.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You have to download composer.phar in you repository.
Then you launch it with the php binary 7.0 or 7.1.

```
/usr/bin/php70 ~/work/composer.phar install
```

or

```
/usr/bin/php71 ~/work/composer.phar install
```

And you can configure your script to use php 7.0 or php 7.1

I hope it will help you

Oliver