# Composer install and update: why does it not set the PHP interpretor in the "vendor" folder?

Tags: composer-php

According to docs, `composer install` (`composer update` too, since it includes `install` script), among other things, downloads the `requirements` and puts these packages inside the `vendor` directory: https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies :

> It then implicitly runs the install command. This will download the dependencies' files into the vendor directory in your project.

What the docs don't say is: we often write the following in `composer.JSON`...

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.0",
```

... so if we try to apply what the docs say, it means that Composer would download the PHP interpretor (a package available in Packagist for example) and put it inside the `vendor` directory, when we run either `composer install` or `composer update`. What is the interest of putting a PHP interpretor inside a site's folder (here, `vendor`)?

But we know it doesn't do that. It won't download any PHP interpretor. It won't obviously put it inside the `vendor` directory. Instead, it will just check the server's PHP interpretor's version and returns a fatal error or something else if this version doesn't match the `requirement`'s version.

**So does it mean that in the Composer's `install` and `update` scripts, there is an exception made for PHP when treating the `require`'s lines in the `composer.JSON` file?**

Comment: Yes you're right, in composer there's a special exception for require `php` , it only checks if your system's PHP version meets the requirement.

Comment: @aceraven777 Thank you! Did you find it in github? Which file which line please? - don't hesitate to write an answer, I would be pleased to accept it.

Comment: You can find it on the composer website, its hard to find though. `require and require-dev also support references to specific PHP versions and PHP extensions your project needs to run successfully.` https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links

Comment: Well. It *seems* to mean there is a treatment exception made for the line `PHP` in `require` but it is not *litterally* written :-) (I've upvoted your comments)

Comment: okay, thanks. Ill write an answer for this

Comment: Please share more details - what do you mean by "download the PHP interpretor"? Packagist does not install PHP itself

Comment: @NicoHaase if we apply what the docs say, Composer would put a PHP interpretor package inside `vendor`, but indeed like you say, in practice we can see that Composer doesn't do that and that no PHP interpretor package exist in Packagist. So what does it mean to write `php` as a `requirement` in `composer.JSON`, this is the question. :-)

Comment: No, it does not, and the documentation doesn't try to tell you that. The excerpt aceraven777 has posted is given in the official documentation. And what that line does has been answered some times on SO, for example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277151/force-composer-to-require-php-version-between-version-x-and-version-y - if you have any further question about this, please edit your question to contain it

Comment: If you read https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies, it clearly says: "It then implicitly runs the install command. This will download the dependencies' files into the vendor directory in your project.", meaning that PHP would be treated like a package to be put in `vendor`. I've answered my question.

Comment: Have you seen https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links? "require and require-dev also support references to specific PHP versions and PHP extensions your project needs to run successfully"

Comment: @NicoHaase yse and it doesn't answer my question. It doesn't tell if or if not, and why or why not, it will or won't put an eventual PHP interpretor package that would be downloaded for example from Packagist in `vendor`, as the docs say `require` do it (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies). Please read my answer to my question.

Comment: What makes you think that it even **could** be Composer's job to add a PHP interpreter to the vendor folder? As Composer installs PHP packages, but never states that it could be able to install PHP itself (as, pretty obvious, Composer - written in PHP - wouldn't run without PHP being installed), this looks pretty obvious to me

Comment: I didn't think so. I was highlighting what you have just said, to show that the docs statement "composer require" will install in vendor folder the requirements put in "composer. Json" 's "require" is wrong because it excludes the notion of virtual/plateform packages (which is presented latter in the docs, see my answer).

Comment: Note that I explain it from my sentence "But we know it doesn't do that." in the OP.

Comment: If you think that the documentation should get improved, feel free to open a bug ticket, or even a pull request with the suggest change, at https://github.com/composer/getcomposer.org

Answer (score 1):

In composer there's a special exception for require php, it only checks if your system's PHP version meets the requirement.

It's in the composer website under **Package links**: https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links.

Its not literally written though, its quite hard to find in the composer documentation.

Comment: Please share more details - what kind of "consistent proof" are you looking for?

Comment: @NicoHaase Either a soruce file + line, or statements in the docs. I've found docs statements. (see my answer)

Comment: Why not search through the source files? Composer is open source, and the specific sections in the documentation have been linked in the comments to your initial question

Comment: Because @aceraven777's comment/asnwer doesn't exactly answer my question."require and require-dev also support references to specific PHP versions and PHP extensions your project needs to run successfully." is not related to `vendor` directory.

Answer (score 1):

If your `require` contains something like with

```
    "php": "^8.0",
    "ext-json": "*",
```

this does not mean: Install PHP or the JSON extension through Composer, but require that PHP and that extension in the given versions are already installed. That's what the documentation at https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links tells you:

> `require` and `require-dev` also support references to specific PHP versions and PHP extensions your project needs to run successfully.

A regular expression that matches all such platform requirements can be found at https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/9ba042ded8b26230d33ebceb692bf29111d51ba4/src/Composer/Repository/PlatformRepository.php#L34 - currently, it contains:

> `const PLATFORM_PACKAGE_REGEX = '{^(?:php(?:-64bit|-ipv6|-zts|-debug)?|hhvm|(?:ext|lib)-[a-z0-9](?:[_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*|composer-(?:plugin|runtime)-api)$}iD';`

...which matches:

- PHP runtimes in several versions
- HHVM, a virtual machine that runs a forked version of PHP
- all kinds of extensions and core libraries, like `ext-json`  or `lib-bz2`
- Composer itself, as some packages require special features of Composer v2 which were not available in v1

Answer (score 0):

All lines in `require` section of `composer.JSON` are not packages available on a repository like Packagist: indeed, we can put some "virtual packages" inside this `require` section (https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages).

`php` is one of these virtual packages. So Composer treat the following line...

```
"require": {
    "php": "^8.0",
```

... as a virtual package (other name: "plateform package"), and not a package that could be put in `vendor`.

Then, if we extend a little the following definition of `require`...

> Map of packages required by this package. The package will not be installed unless those requirements can be met.

(https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require)

..., then we can say that "if server's PHP interpretor's version doesn't meet the requirements versions, then Composer will raise a fatal error or something like that.

**Conclusion: being seen as a "virtual/plateform package" by Composer, `php` won't be installed (put) in `vendor` directory. It will just make Composer to check if server PHP version matches or not the requirements (if not, an error will be raised). This behavior is different than for other packages that would be, them, downloaded from for example Packagist and installed (put) inside `vendor` directory. **

Comment: "All lines in require section of composer.JSON are not packages available on a repository like Packagist" - what do you mean by that? Usually, the `require` section contains numerous packages that can be found on Packagist

Comment: Pease read the docs https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages. This is entirely what my question is about. If you put: `php: X.Y.Z` in `composer.JSON` in `require`, it won't be treated as a package that would for example be available in Packagist. It will be treated as a "plateform package" (read my answer).