# Install & use Composer for dynamic PHP version

Tags: php, composer-php, wamp, mamp, mamp-pro

On my local machine I have MAMP PRO running, which allows the change of PHP version per project independently.

Composer is installed on a specific PHP version, but my project aren't.

How would I use composer so that it will either use the PHP version of the local environment, or so that I can easily tell Composer that I am using PHP "x.x.x".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force composer to require PHP Version between Version X and Version Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277151/force-composer-to-require-php-version-between-version-x-and-version-y)

Comment: Not exactly, but It's good that it's here right now.

Comment: Can you share more details about that? The most upvoted answers in that linked question provide the exact same hint that you've accepted in this question

Comment: The question is obviously not the same. The most upvoted answer there doesn't answer his question, since that he's asked for a version between 2 php versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this thing: https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform

```
{
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            //"php": "/path/to/php or php version"
            "php": "7.0.3"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using the `composer.phar` file downloaded for each project, rather than the global installation of composer.
For example

`php7.4 composer.phar install`
or
`php8.2 composer.phar install` or etc.

For downloading composer.phar

```bash
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

ps: don't forget to add composer.phar to gitignore.

Comment: Please share more details. Why should running the exact same phar file with different PHP versions require multiple copies of that file?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @NicoHaase Right it's wrong.
It is also possible to use `php7.4 /bin/composer install`.
But the above answer seems to suit the questioner.